# Does a linear function $\mathrm {End}_K(V) \otimes V \to V$ which maps $A \otimes v$ to $A(v)$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

$K$ is a field and $V$ a finite dimensional $K$-vector space.

Does a linear function $\mathrm {End}_K(V) \otimes V \to V$ which maps $A \otimes v$ to $A(v)$, for all
$A \in \mathrm {End}_K(V)$ and all $v \in V$ exist?

Comment: is the  map defined on $\mathrm{End(V)} \times V \to V$ by $(A,v) \mapsto A(v)$ bilinear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact more is true. Recall that for any vector spaces $V,W$ the set of homomorphisms $\operatorname{Hom}_K(V,W)$ carries the pointwise vector space structure. By showing (I leave this up to you) that the map
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\operatorname{Hom}_K(V,W)\times V &\longrightarrow&W\\
(\phi,v)&\longmapsto&\phi(v)
\end{array}$$
is bilinear, we obtain the corresponding linear map
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\operatorname{Hom}_K(V,W)\otimes V &\longrightarrow&W\\
\phi\otimes v&\longmapsto&\phi(v)
\end{array}$$
This is the counit of the so called *tensor-hom-adjunction*, which will become important later in your algebraic career.

The case $V=W$ has $\operatorname{Hom}_K(V,V)=\operatorname{End}_K(V)$.

Comment: It is also worth noting, perhaps, that we can equivalently find a natural isomorphism between $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W) \otimes V$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(V) \otimes W$. As a map over $\operatorname{Hom}(V) \otimes W$, this "adjunction" is simply a trace.